# Getting URL that caused 404 error C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is there away to find out the URL that has caused the 404 error.

I have a custom error page set up, and within that I am trying to catch what the URL that caused the 404 error is.

Getting the requested URL just returns the current 404 page.

Comment: Look in your web server log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the page that actually threw the error, it will be posted to the query string when directed to your custom error page.

```
Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"];
```

Comment: Depends on the .NET version. 4.5+ no longer shows the `aspxerrorpath` querystring. You'd have to do something like `Request.RawUrl` on the custom error page to get it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing DGibbs, I haven't done this in my newer projects.